# Typescript: Export the same function with different names

Tags: typescript

I have a function that i need to export under two different names without redeclaring it.

Right now i'm stuck at doing this:

```
function handle() {
    console.log('handle');
}


export function post {
    return handle();
}

export function get() {
    return handle();
}
```

But it doesn't scale well and it's ugly, especially if i have parameters that i need to pass to `handle`.

Ideally it would look something like this, but it's not valid syntax:

```
function handle() {
    console.log('handle');
}

export {handle} as get;

export {handle} as post;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that you need to change your TypeScript code. You will find more info at the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

```
function handle() {
    console.log('handle');
}

export { handle as get };
export { handle as post };
```

And then you can import it as you want

```
import { get } from './your-file-path';
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you could have skipped the "you just need to write well your TypeScript" part. Are you implying that i don't care to write proper code?

Comment: No, I do not know to speak English :) I will change it. Sorry

Comment: Understood. I think your answer is more correct than mine since it allows me to export functions as functions, while mine will assign them to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution:

```
function handle() {
    console.log('handle');
}

export let get = handle;

export let post = handle;
```